# windows 10 pip install 'Failed Connection'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

This is the error I get from running `pip install numpy` on windows command prompt. This error also occurs with the other packages I have tried. I logged into cmd as an admin, but ended up with the same result. I am connected to the internet so that is not the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05DD03F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Comment: Are you behind some proxy?

Comment: might be, how do I check?

Comment: Just get rid off all the pip problems with using anaconda. You don't need to challanging yourself for this kind of issues.

Comment: The suggestion by @ihsancemil is sensible with Windows. Unrelated to your current issue, but installing the scientific stack on Windows is an absolute pain at times, so it's usually easier just to get Anaconda which will fix all of it and your current issue disappears in the process

Comment: Sure that might be a good work around, but it doesn't fit the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10:
Go to start->Network proxy settings->disable 'Use a proxy server' in Manual proxy setup.

Now, try to install again using `pip install numpy`

Hope, this helps.