Unable to pip install ISLP package
Going through Intro. Statistical Learning with Python right now and at the point where I want to start using python. The book instructs us to create an environment for the purpose of the pedagogy, which I have done, then install the ISLP package using pip, which I attempted but was then met with the following (see image) error message. In particular, the red error text(s) I received said:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ISLP (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ISLP

I then checked out the github for statlearning, as was advised if encountering a 'frozen environment' - which I don't think I did but it was my only recourse - and there I was advised to use the command
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/intro-stat-learning/ISLP_labs/v2.1.3/requirements.txt;

Which you can also see in the attached image and was met with a 404 url not found error.
My question is, does anyone have experience with these errors and can give me an idea on how to ameliorate this problem, or any experience with ISLP and the process of getting the labs to run that can explain how to do so.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I tried exactly what I listed above. I expect the ISLP package to install then I could start the lab by calling jupyter notebooks and the specific lab file from the conda shell.

I see WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, conect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by every day here. Test the command with other internet provider or by using a VPN, proxy or Tor network. I live in Iran and here the government plays with the internet every day to impose more restrictions on users. So problems like yours can be seen here every day. For your second error, just remove trailing semicolon from the URL.

The error shows that your computer is having trouble resolving the IP address of the Python package repository, which is pypi.org by default. Are you able to visit https://pypi.org in your browser? Could you share the output of pip -vvv install ISLP?

May relate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740901/windows-10-pip-install-failed-connection

PIP
For me the simple pip install ISLP worked. I would suggest to start with a fresh new environment in conda:
conda create --name env_ISLP python=3.8
pip install ISLP

Maybe your conda env lack of python, which is one potential issue (check with conda list what's inside you env and update you're question if possible).
(To me you issue with pip seems only a connection failure, maybe you do have some VPN that interferes with it?)
URL
The URL that you're trying to use is wrong. ; should not be included.
The URL you provided though links simply to a list of libraries to install as follows:
numpy==1.24.2
scipy==1.11.1
pandas==1.5.3
lxml==4.9.3
scikit-learn==1.3.0
joblib==1.3.1
statsmodels==0.14.0
lifelines==0.27.7
pygam==0.9.0
l0bnb==1.0.0
torch==2.0.1
torchvision==0.15.2
pytorch-lightning==2.0.6
torchinfo==1.8.0
torchmetrics==1.0.1
ISLP==0.3.20


when I get this retrying error, I use VPN for installing and its done!
I don't know why pip give this error in these days.
